# Is the same file tokenized every time I include it?

Tags: php, parsing

This question is about the PHP parsing engine.

When I include a file multiple times in a single runtime, does PHP tokenize it every time or does it keep a cache and just run the compiled code on subsequent inclusions?

**EDIT:** More details: I am not using an external caching mechanism and I am dealing with the *same* file being included multiple times during *the same request*.

**EDIT 2:** The file I'm trying to include contains procedural code. I want it to be executed every time I `include()` it, I am just curious if PHP internally keeps track of the tokenized version of the file for speed reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the file is parsed every time it is (really) included, even within the same php instance.
But there are opcode caches like e.g. [apc](http://de.php.net/apc)

```
<?php
$i = 'include_test.php';

file_put_contents($i, '<?php $x = 1;');
include $i;
echo $x, ' ';

file_put_contents($i, '<?php $x = 2;');
include $i;
echo $x, ' '
```

```
1 2
```

(ok, weak proof. PHP could check whether the file's mtime has changed. And that what apc does, I think. But without a cache PHP really doesn't)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a PHP bytecode cache such as APC.  That will accomplish what you want, to re-use a compiled version of a PHP page on subsequent requests.  Otherwise, PHP reads the file, tokenizes and compiles it on every request.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [include_once()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php).
It will include it again.

Also if you are using objects. Look at [__autoload()](http://is.php.net/autoload)

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a basic test, much like VolkerK's.  Here's what I tested:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('include.php','<?php echo $i . "<br />"; ?>');

for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){
    include('include.php');
    if($i == 5){
        file_put_contents('include.php','<?php echo $i+$i; echo "<br />"; ?>');
    }
}

?>
```

This generated the following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
12
14
16
18
```

So, unless it caches based on mtime of the file, it seems it parses every include.  You would likely want to use [include_once()](https://www.php.net/include_once) instead of standard include().  Hope that helps!