# Performance impact when require-ing a file many times vs reusing it

Tags: php, caching, filesystems

Think of PHP templating.

I was recently contemplating whether it makes sense to read a template file once, storing it in memory, and then parsing it (replace placeholders with values, e.g.) rather than require-ing that file as many times as you need it. A usage scenario would be a list with list items templated as separate files. The first thoughts I had were inclined towards the former solution, because I reckon replacing values would be an easier operation than requiring the file from the file system. Later, however, I realized that pretty much all hard disk drives (or other storage, for that matter) have their own caching, and requiring the same file over and over, will not result in it being re-read each time, but rather re-served from the cache.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you include a file, PHP has to parse it. This penalty can be offset using an opcode cache like APC. If your templates don't contain any PHP (which it sounds like they don't), I would recommend loading the template into memory once and then re-using it as needed.

Another thing to keep in mind when looking to optimize your code is make sure you can measure the change. Use something like [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to profile your code and measure what effect your changes are having.

**Edit**

Since the files do currently contain PHP, take a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804897/is-the-same-file-tokenized-every-time-i-include-it). I would recommend putting a function in the file so that it only needs to be loaded once, but can be called multiple times with different parameters.

Comment: The template files would most probably contain PHP statements, at least stuff like "echo $foo"

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "disk cache" you're actually referring to the  page cache? [Wikipedia: Page Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)

If so I wouldn't really be inclined to trust something like this with the performance of my application. Don't forget the page cache only uses UNUSED memory and will happily spit it back out when needed.

I would be inclined to use something like APC as an object cache, this has the great side effect of not having to actually rewrite any of your code as it's all done behind the scenes. Another possibility would be to just assign your template to a variable and constantly reuse that. Or, if you wanted to you could even use Memcache, this kind of stuff is more useful for caching database returns though, or large datasets.

Sorry for the slightly incoherent ramblings...

Comment: I understand your first point Garry, however think about the fact that if a file is cached (Page Cache), then the OS will most probably not have time/reasons to spit it out within the following 50ms when the code pertaining to the re-inclusion of the same template file will take place.

Answer (score 0):

> I was recently contemplating

That's quite wrong of you.
Groundless contemplating out of nowhere seldom does any good but most likely will put you in a trouble. Just out of nowhere.

Instead of contemplating, one have to do *profiling*.
Of course no to measure any changes, like H Hatfeld said, but to determine, if they need any changes at all. Most of time it turns out that you were barking wrong tree.
Profiling is the right thing to make you bark the right one.

> whether it makes sense to read a template file onc, estoring it in memory, and then parsing it

For the highload(or bloated) projects it makes.
So, PHP already have such a feature, called `bytecode cache`. There is a [plenty of the thing on the market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators), at our company we are using eAccelerator.

But most of time default every-request parsing is enough.
You are absolutely right about filesystem cache and parsing being blazingly fast, much faster than usual application logic, which has to be optimized at the first place.

Comment: Beg to differ about contemplating there, Sir. Good points throughout, however. Note that I didn't say profiling isn't good. It's just that profiling is much more than one test, in one system. This is where contemplating comes into play; and it should be used always, in the first place, then profiling. My 2 cents.

Comment: Where wasn't any reasons listed in your question. that's why I took it as just a groundless assumption